# How to trigger a function every time when I select a new option in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2 (TypeScript).

How do you trigger a function, such as `onChange()`, whenever when I select a new option?

When I searched online, all I found was information about `ng-change` in Angular 1. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

```
<select [(ng-model)]="selectedDevices">
    <option *ng-for="#i of devices">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate on what you said - `When I searched online, all I found was information about `ng-change` in Angular 1` -   what did you find ?

Comment: Added detail, thanks for suggestion @Coffee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since angular2 ties directly into DOM events, you can just listen to the change event:

```
 <select [(ng-model)]="selectedDevices" (change)="changeHandler($event)">
```

And then in your component:

```
 public changeHandler($event) {
   // do something here
 }
```

Comment: Wow, that is simple! Thanks

Comment: But I have another question, for button they use (click), for form they use (ng-submit), now I know for select they use (change). Is there a place having all of these info?

Comment: Not that I've found, but your first attempts to handle something like this is to look to the native DOM events first. The team is excited to get rid of a lot of ng1 directives in ng2, so you might be able to find a list of deprecated directives that will express this move to native DOM events